# Overriding protected variable c++

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have the following code:

```cpp
class Board
{
  protected:
    std::vector<Piece*> pieces;
}

class ChessBoard : public Board
{
  protected:
    std::vector<ChessPiece*> pieces;

}
```

I am wanting the derived class to override the protected variable `pieces` with this new `vector`, however I am having difficulty with it, and it seems like this is bad practice.

Comment: You can't override *data members*, only *`virtual` methods*.  Your `ChessBoard::pieces` member is [*shadowing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `Board::pieces` member. What is your actual *goal* with this code? Please be more specific.

Comment: its not bad practice, because it isnt possible. [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ? Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The ChessPiece class is a derived class of Piece and has some member functions that Piece doesn't have. So if I leave pieces as type Piece* I get errors such as "class Piece" has no member function ...

Comment: @adammoyle In that case, you would have to either 1) introduce `virtual` methods into `Piece` that `CheckPiece` can override (preferred), or 2) type-cast a `Piece*` to `CheckPiece*` when you need to access `ChessPiece`-specific functionality (less preferred).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! Yes, I understand now that solves all my problems. Solved

Comment: If you find the interface of `ChessPiece` is different enough from `Piece` that you can't use a `ChessPiece` as a `Piece`, the is-a relationship implied by inheritance may not the the right choice. See the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle).

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, unfortunately, I have wasted everyone's time. I simply needed to cast the piece to the type I wanted and it solved everything. The second vector was an attempt to solve that problem but is no longer need. Thank you for the time and effort you put in and sorry for wasting it

Comment: You learned something. Time wasn't wasted. That said, see if you can get what you want with `virtual` functions rather than casting. It tends to scale better.

Comment: @adammoyle: As a note: I find that having "data" classes that use virtual inheritance causes chaos and headaches. Prefer to reserve virtual inheritance for "logic" classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as "overriding a variable", whether protected or otherwise.

In your example program, the class `ChessBoard` contains a member sub object `pieces` and a base sub object `Board` that contains the member `Board::pieces`. Thus, there are two vectors inside the object.

Object oriented programming is achieved through virtual functions. You haven't explained what you're trying to do (beyond something that cannot be done) so this is just a guess, but maybe you are looking for covariant return types:

```
class Board
{
    protected:
        virtual Piece&
        operator[](std::size_t index) = 0;

    public:
        virtual ~Board() = default;
};

class ChessBoard : public Board
{
    std::vector<ChessPiece> pieces;

    protected:
        virtual ChessPiece&
        operator[](std::size_t index) override;
};
```

Furthermore, if the sub classes have identical base and/or member function implementations except for the types, then you can avoid repetition by using a template.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me. However, suppose ChessPiece has member functions that Piece doesn't have and thus I can't leave the vector as type Piece* or else I raise errors such as "class Piece" has no member function ...

Comment: @adammoyle Then change the element type.

Comment: Thank you for putting the effort in I was just being dense. My whole solution was solved by type-casting. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: opinionated nitpick: Imho object oriented programming is much more than virtuals and more than inheritance. Runtime polymorphism is achieved through virtual functions.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 OOP is certainly more than virtual functions, but they are in my opinion the most essential, core part of OOP. A counter-nitpick: Runtime polymorphism is more than just virtual functions :)

Comment: Interesting. I appreciate different views and opinions (seriously). Unfortunately this isnt the place to discuss.